# android opengl ndk - unimplemented OpenGL ES API error

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, 2d

I am writing a pure c++ application for android using the NDK.
I am trying to write a simple app that does 2D drawing with OpenGL, so no textures or anything like that.

I applied all the recommendations posted here and am still getting the

***called unimplemented OpenGL ES API***

messages in logcat

Here's my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- BEGIN_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.native_activity"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"></uses-feature>
    <!-- This is the platform API where NativeActivity was introduced. -->
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />
    <!-- This .apk has no Java code itself, so set hasCode to false. -->
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:hasCode="false">
        <!-- Our activity is the built-in NativeActivity framework class.
             This will take care of integrating with our NDK code. -->
        <activity android:name="android.app.NativeActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
            <!-- Tell NativeActivity the name of or .so -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                    android:value="native-activity" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And here's the code:

```
EGLDisplay dpy;
EGLSurface surface;
EGLContext context;

static void android_handle_cmd( struct android_app * app, int32_t cmd ) {

    switch (cmd) {

        case APP_CMD_INIT_WINDOW:

            // The window is being shown, get it ready.
            if ( NULL != app->window ) {

                Init( app );
                drawscreen();

            }
            break;

    }

}


void pixel( int x, int y ) {

    if ( NULL == GLapp.surface ) {

        return;

    }    

    glColor4f( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0 );
    glVertexAttrib2f( 0, x + 0.5, y + 0.5 );

}


void drawscreen( void ) {

    if ( NULL == GLapp.surface ) {

        return;

    }

    eglSwapBuffers( GLapp.dpy, GLapp.surface );

}


int Init( struct android_app * app ) {

    dpy = eglGetDisplay( EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY );

    eglInitialize( dpy, 0, 0 );

    const EGLint attribs[] = {

        EGL_SURFACE_TYPE,    EGL_WINDOW_BIT,

        EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT, // <--- OpenGL ES 2.0

        EGL_BLUE_SIZE,       8,
        EGL_GREEN_SIZE,      8,
        EGL_RED_SIZE,        8,

        EGL_NONE

    };

    EGLConfig config;
    EGLint numConfigs;

    eglChooseConfig( dpy, attribs, &config, 1, &numConfigs );

    EGLint format;

    eglGetConfigAttrib( dpy, config, EGL_NATIVE_VISUAL_ID, &format );

    ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry( app->window, 0, 0, format );

    surface = eglCreateWindowSurface( dpy, config, app->window, NULL );

    const EGLint ContextAttribList[] = {

        EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2,
        EGL_NONE

    };

    context = eglCreateContext( GLapp.dpy, config, EGL_NO_CONTEXT, ContextAttribList );

    eglMakeCurrent( dpy, surface, surface, context );

    int XSize;
    eglQuerySurface( GLapp.dpy, GLapp.surface, EGL_WIDTH, &XSize );

    int YSize;
    eglQuerySurface( GLapp.dpy, GLapp.surface, EGL_HEIGHT, &YSize );

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );

    glLoadIdentity();

    glOrthof( 0, XSize, YSize, 0, 0, 1 );

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );

    /* Displacement trick for exact pixelization */
    glTranslatef( 0.375, 0.375, 0 );

    glDisable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );

    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    return 0;

}
```

I removed all the error checking code to make the code easier to read.
The Init function executes without there being any errors detected, it's only when I call the pixel or drawscreen (not sure which) function that the log fills up with the 'unimplemented OpenGL ES API' error

Can anyone help?

Comment: You should have some sort of stacktrace / error message that would be helpful to find the problem. Please append that to you question.

Comment: unimplemented OpenGL ES API IS the error. Apart from that, logcat displays nothing suspicious. The code runs on a Nexus, but doesn't display anything, THAT'S the error. Sorry I wasn't clearer

Answer (score 0):

Your application is lacking of inclusions and we don't even know about possible errors during the building phase.

My suggestion is to look at the several samples in the NDK folder and learn from them.

Considering a native activity with OpenGL ES code you should at least include:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <EGL/egl.h>
#include <GLES/gl.h>

#include <android/log.h>
#include <android_native_app_glue.h>
```

but this is just to give you an idea, you probably want more than that.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for gles 2 but you're using things like glMatrixMode which aren't gles2 apis - don't include gl.h, use gles2.h instead - that's got the api you're asking for in it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

I'm very much a noob with OpenGL. It never occurred to me you couldn't mix API calls like that.

Maybe I've complicated things too much.

I'm trying to port a very simple OpenGL app to android.

The APIs the non-android app calls are very basic OpenGL and I've tried everything I can think of to get the same thing working on Android, including looking at how other Android apps initialize OpenGL, so this is how I came to such a mish-mash solution.

Comment: In fact, I'm trying to do something VERY simple: Use OpenGL as a 2D drawing tool. Put even more simply, I want to be able to address the display as a two-dimensional matrix of pixels.

The original code used freeglut to set up OpenGL but freeglut doesn't exist on Android.

Comment: The non-android code initializes like this:

    int XSize = 1024;
    int YSize = 768;
    
    glutInit( &argc, argv );

    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB );

    glutInitWindowSize( XSize, YSize );

    glutCreateWindow( "gltest" );
    
    glutDisplayFunc( drawscreen );

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    
    glLoadIdentity();

    glOrtho( 0, XSize, YSize, 0, 0, 1 );
    
    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    
    glTranslatef( 0.375, 0.375, 0 );

    glDisable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );

    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

Comment: As you can see the lines following glMatrixMode (that set up the 2D display) are the same.

Then, sandwiched between calls to glBegin and glEnd, calls to the pixel function drew an image on the screen one dot at a time and then the drawscreen function would render it onto the display.

That's all I'm trying to do here, no 3D or textures. It must be possible to do the same thing with Opengl on Android, only I am such an OpenGL newbie that I haven't figured out how...

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Use gles 1, not 2 - change the gles version feature flag in the android manifest to say version 1, change the EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION to 1 in the code, etc - get another tutorial that deals with gles1 - you don't want to be dealing with gles2 if you're just porting an old-style gl app.

Comment: If I change the code to this:
EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES_BIT,

I get this output in logcat

I/jni/main.c( 1880): 00294DB8: Wed Aug 22 18:17:34 2012: gl.cpp line 376: Android GL init start
D/libEGL  ( 1880): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
D/libEGL  ( 1880): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
D/libEGL  ( 1880): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
I/jni/main.c( 1880): 00294DB8: Wed Aug 22 18:17:34 2012: gl.cpp line 444: eglCreateContext FAILED
E/libEGL  ( 1880): eglMakeCurrent:1212 error 3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)

Comment: If I change the code to this:
EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_BIT,

The application segfaults:
D/libEGL  ( 1994): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
D/libEGL  ( 1994): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
D/libEGL  ( 1994): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
I/DEBUG   (   79): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (   79): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/GT-I9000M/GT-I9000M:2.3.3/GINGERBREAD/GKG3:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG   (   79): pid: 1994, tid: 2001  >>> com.example.native_activity <<<

Comment: I/DEBUG   (   79): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 14957e48
I/DEBUG   (   79):  r0 00000001  r1 000000b4  r2 14656a40  r3 00301408
I/DEBUG   (   79):  r4 0000302e  r5 814656a4  r6 469d5768  r7 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   79):  r8 000000e0  r9 813021b9  10 b000f150  fp 8144b915
I/DEBUG   (   79):  ip 81465728  sp 469d56f8  lr abe0310d  pc abe03062  cpsr 00000030
I/DEBUG   (   79):  d0  2f6d657473797373  d1  17000ce007070035
I/DEBUG   (   79):  d2  0000000000000070  d3  0000000000000063
I/DEBUG   (   79):  d4  0000000000000000  d5  0000000000000000

Comment: It turns out I really DO need gles 2 because glVertexAttrib2f is in libGLESv2

Comment: This explains what I'm trying to do http://basic4gl.wikispaces.com/2D+Drawing+in+OpenGL